# Change the target of a symlink with PHP

Tags: php, linux, symlink

How can I change the target of a symlink with PHP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete the existing link using [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function and recreate the link to the new target using the [symlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) function.

```
symlink($target, $link);
.
.
unlink($link);
symlink($new_target, $link);
```

You need to do error checking for each of these.

Comment: +1 - this is much better than writing the shell stuff yourself.

Comment: okay, i was just seeing if there was a way around having to unlink and then recreate the symlink. thanks!

Comment: This means that the link is unavailable for a (short) time... Dangerous :-(

Answer (score 3):

PHP can execute shell commands using [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) or the [backtick operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

Hence:

```
<?php
`rm thelink`;
`ln -s /path/to/new/place ./thelink`;
```

This will be run as the user which is running the Apache server, so you might need to keep that in mind.

Comment: Shell commands should be avoided when there are built-in alternatives.

Comment: Replace `ln -s` with `ln -sf` (and remove `rm`) and this solution becomes better than the accepted solution, as it atomically (on linux/unix) replaces the target of the link, with no interruption. As it seems there is no PHP function/option to do that (`symlink()` has no *force* option).

Answer (score 0):

To do this atomically, without the risk of deleting the original symlink and failing to create the new one, you should use the `ln` system command like so:

```php
system(
    'ln --symbolic --force --no-dereference ' .
        escapeshellarg($new_target) . ' ' .
        escapeshellarg($link),
    $relinked
);
if (0 === $relinked) {
    # success
}
else {
    # failure
}
```

The `force` flag is necessary to update existing links without failing, and `no-dereference` avoids the rookie mistake of accidentally putting a link inside the old symlink's target directory.

It's wise to `chdir()` to the directory that will contain `$link` if using relative paths.